# Class seems incomplete at the point of implicit instantiation, can instantiated function legally use it?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer

I must be missing something really obvious here. Consider two examples below:

```
struct Test;

int bar()
{
    return sizeof(Test);   // (1), compilation error: Test is incomplete
}

struct Test
{
    char x[123456];
};
```

The first example cannot be compiled for obvious reason: struct `Test` is incomplete at line marked `(1)` and hence any expression that requires complete type would fail. That's understandable.

```
template <typename T>
int foo()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

struct Test;

int bar()
{
    return foo<Test>();    // (2): no error.
}

struct Test
{
    char x[123456];
};
```

However, this second example compiles just fine and that surprises me a lot.

My naiive understanding of implicit template instantiation suggested that `foo<Test>()` is instantiated at line marked `(2)` and that class `Test` is still incomplete at that point. Which made me think that applying `sizeof` operator to it would result in the same compilation error.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:17),source:%27template+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aint+foo()%0A%7B%0A++++return+sizeof(T)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+Test%3B%0A%0Aint+bar()%0A%7B%0A++++return+foo%3CTest%3E()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+Test%0A%7B%0A++++char+x%5B123456%5D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) proves me wrong even with `--std=c++98` -- generated assembler code shows that foo<> returns correct value, and another [godbolt dashboard](https://godbolt.org/z/G7M9Thdhb) (thanks, Marek R!) shows that this example seems valid across several compilers and standard options. I can't figure out why... So my questions are:

1. Does that second code snippet constitute a well-formed program according to C++17 standard?
2. What is the point of instantiation of function `foo<Test>()`?
3. Why is `Test` treated as a completely defined class in the body of instantiated `foo<>()`?

**Edit:**
The question linked as a duplicate asked a different question. It asked: "is **the compiler** conforming?" and the answer was: "yes, the compiler is allowed to do that". This question, on the contrary, asks: "is **the code** well-formed?" (see question #1 above) and the answer, judging by the comments, seems to be "no, it's ill-formed".

Comment: [better godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G7M9Thdhb).

Comment: Related/dupe: [Can the point-of-instantiation be delayed until the end of the translation unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030403/can-the-point-of-instantiation-be-delayed-until-the-end-of-the-translation-unit).

Comment: Adding constexpr [confuses clang](https://godbolt.org/z/zfx8Pxb7Y).

Comment: @MarekR Not really confusing it. Clang just seems to decide to instantiate `constexpr` function template specialization earlier. Either way is permitted by the standard.

Comment: Recap answer: There are two possible points of instantiation. One after `bar`'s definition and one at the end of the translation unit. If they give different meaning to instantiations (as is the case here) the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. Basically the compiler can choose either point to actually try the instantiation. It may compile or may not compile, no guarantees.

Comment: @user17732522, "If they give different meaning to instantiations (as is the case here) the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required." -- I think that's the answer I was looking for. Would you mind converting this comment to an answer, if I can have this question reopened?